# Converting JSON number to_i returning 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I've been given this hash:

```
{
    "item": {
        "icon": "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4332_obj_sprite.gif?id=4798",
        "icon_large": "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4332_obj_big.gif?id=4798",
        "id": 4798,
        "type": "Ammo",
        "typeIcon": "http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo",
        "name": "Adamant brutal",
        "description": "Blunt adamantite arrow...ouch",
        "current": {
            "trend": "neutral",
            "price": 227
        },
        "today": {
            "trend": "neutral",
            "price": 0
        },
        "day30": {
            "trend": "positive",
            "change": "+1.0%"
        },
        "day90": {
            "trend": "positive",
            "change": "+1.0%"
        },
        "day180": {
            "trend": "positive",
            "change": "+2.0%"
        },
        "members": "true"
    }
}
```

I obtain the current price like this:

```
class GpperxpController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def cooking
    require 'open-uri'

    @sharkid = '385'
    @sharkurl = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=#{@sharkid}"
    @sharkpage = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@sharkurl))
    @sharkinfo = JSON.parse(@sharkpage.text)
    @sharkinfo = @sharkinfo['item']['current']['price']
  end
end
```

`<%= @sharkinfo %>` in my view returns 227. However, I want to perform some math operations on it, which is why I must use `.to_i`. Only problem is when I append `.to_i`, the value changes to 1. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Price in the given json (http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=385) contains `,`.

```
... "current":{"trend":"neutral","price":"1,844"},...
                                           ^
```

Remove `,` before call `String#to_i`.

```
"1,844".to_i
# => 1
"1,844".gsub(',', '').to_i
# => 1844
```

Answer (score 1):

Just running irb, and putting your JSON response in a variable, I had no problem getting the response to be 227, either by pulling the price out as text and then converting to an integer or by pulling the price out as an integer in one fell swoop.

So my initial code looked like:

```
json_text = '''
{
"item": {
    "icon": "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4332_obj_sprite.gif?id=4798",
    "icon_large": "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/4332_obj_big.gif?id=4798",
    "id": 4798,
    "type": "Ammo",
    "typeIcon": "http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Ammo",
    "name": "Adamant brutal",
    "description": "Blunt adamantite arrow...ouch",
    "current": {
        "trend": "neutral",
        "price": 227
    },
    "today": {
        "trend": "neutral",
        "price": 0
    },
    "day30": {
        "trend": "positive",
        "change": "+1.0%"
    },
    "day90": {
        "trend": "positive",
        "change": "+1.0%"
    },
    "day180": {
        "trend": "positive",
        "change": "+2.0%"
    },
    "members": "true"
}
'''
require 'json'
si = JSON.parse(json_text)
```

And then either of the following:

```
p = si['item']['current']['price']
price = p.to_i
```

or

```
price = si['item']['current']['price'].to_i
```

put the value of 227 in my price variable.

Something I would avoid if I were you though, is using the same variable name for different things.  If what you want to have is the integer price in @sharkinfo, then you would do well to have a temporary name (without the @ symbol) to put the price as text in, then assign the integer value to the desired variable.

Try this and see if it helps.  I'll try to monitor this for a bit to see if you get anywhere.  Also, at the point you pull the text out of the JSON, I believe this ceases to be a JSON problem any longer.  Finally, you might include what version of ruby and what platform (Windows/Mac/Linux/etc) you are using.

Comment: And I see falsetru's answer below, which is much better than mine.  The JSON text you were having trouble with wasn't the JSON text you had in your question.  Better questions tend to get better answers.  :)